# Href V/s Form submit

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, href, form-submit

I want to delete (or update) a record in `MySql` through `PHP`. The options here are :

**One.**

```
<a href="process.php?pid=3&cid=10" role="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

**Two.**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="pid" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="cid" value="10"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></form>
```

Later, I will redirect from `process.php`. So, Which is better and may I know why?

In both options, it is working (delete or other). I just want to ask any advantages in form submit

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436205/get-or-post-for-deletion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET or POST for deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436205/get-or-post-for-deletion)

Comment: @Anant both are working for me. I just want to know which is advantageous over one-another

Answer (score 0):

> One :- Using get method

```
<a href="process.php?pid=3&cid=10" role="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

> Two :- Using Post method

```
<form action="process.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="pid" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="cid" value="10"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></form>
```

## Compare Get and post method :

> Get Method ( Advantages and disadvantages )

1. Since the data sent by the GET method are displayed in the URL, it
   is possible to bookmark the page with specific query string values.
2. The GET method is not suitable for passing sensitive information
       such as the username and password, because these are fully visible
       in the URL query string as well as potentially stored in the client
       browser's memory as a visited page.
3. Because the GET method assigns data to a server environment
       variable, the length of the URL is limited. So, there is a
       limitation for the total data to be sent.

> Post method ( Advantages and disadvantages )

1. It is more secure than GET because user-entered information is never
   visible in the URL query string or in the server logs.
2. There is a much larger limit on the amount of data that can be
   passed and one can send text data as well as binary data (uploading
   a file) using POST.
3. Since the data sent by the POST method is not visible in the URL, so
   it is not possible to bookmark the page with specific query.

[thanks](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-get-and-post.php)

Comment: One thing I noticed now in `form-submit` is I can validate the `form` before submit by `javascript`